# iPython Notebook: import folium fails working with domino d3

Tags: dictionary, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, utilities, folium

I am trying to model data similar to this one:
http://blog.dominodatalab.com/creating-interactive-crime-maps-with-folium/ 
but i am using iPython Notebook/Jupyter in the browser through my company's site.

The man from the first domino blog said that if using jupyter, set it up like this for in-line maps: 
https://app.dominodatalab.com/r00sj3/crimemaps/view/examples.ipynb

all great. except i have downloaded and tried to install folium and this is the error that i keep getting in my iPython notebook:

```
import folium

import pandas as pd

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-6e0d97fb4c63> in <module>()
----> 1 import folium
      2 import pandas as pd

/var/vol/notebooks/folium.py in <module>()
     20 from pkg_resources import resource_string
     21 
---> 22 from folium import utilities
     23 from folium.six import text_type, binary_type, iteritems
     24 

ImportError: cannot import name utilities
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't want the utilities import, just folium and I am very confused as to why it won't do anything. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you install `folium`? It seems it is not capable to find the utilities module.

Comment: so i have two different jupyter locations: one run through a browser entirely web-based and the other i launch through terminal. i installed it via terminal and it worked, but when i tried to install it from folium's website so that I could just use the web-based version i keep getting the same error.  i need to import it to the web-based notebook.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. In order to use `folium` you need to install it in a proper location. It seems you are using a local installation and a remote server and in the remote server it is not installed. Please, could you clarify what you are trying to do, your setup, jupyter, folium,..., versions, Operative system,..., and how you are trying to run the software?